# C# LINQ - selecting a dynamic object based on properties defined at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I've been trying to create an expression which can project a strongly typed EF Core entity into a dynamic object containing a list which are defined at runtime using a REST API call.

This is what I have so far:

```
Expression<Func<Message, dynamic>> DynamicFields(IEnumerable<string> fields)
{
    var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Message), "o");
    var xNew = Expression.New(typeof(ExpandoObject));

    var bindings = fields.Select(o => {
        var mi = typeof(Message).GetProperty(o);
        var xOriginal = Expression.Property(xParameter, mi);
        return Expression.Bind(mi, xOriginal);
    });

    var xInit = Expression.MemberInit((dynamic)xNew, bindings);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Message, dynamic>>(xInit, xParameter);
}
```

It feels like I'm super close, but this bombs out at runtime stating that X property is not a member of ExpandoObject. I've tried changing up the use of the dynamic and ExpandoObject, but nothing seems to work - is this even possible?

If I switch out dyanmic / ExpandoObject for Message, it works just fine, but returns an instance of the Message class with all of its properties at their default values.

Anyone done this before?

Cheers.

Comment: Why don't you just cast to dynamic, Why are you creating an expression for this?

Comment: Because I don't know which fields to select until runtime

Comment: Basically you want to dynamically filter your property data set

Comment: Why don't you just pull all the results into a dictionary of key to value, pretty sure the json serializer will create an object out of it by default

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to project to `ExpandoObject` / `dynamic` directly.

But you can project to dynamically created types at runtime. See for instance [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#microsoftentityframeworkcoredynamiclinq) package - 
[Dynamic Data Classes](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#dynamic-data-classes).

If you install that [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq) form nuget (you can develop similar functionality yourself, but you should basically implement all that part of the package is doing), the method in question can be implemented as follows:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

static Expression<Func<TSource, dynamic>> DynamicFields<TSource>(IEnumerable<string> fields)
{
    var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "o");
    var properties = fields
        .Select(f => typeof(TSource).GetProperty(f))
        .Select(p => new DynamicProperty(p.Name, p.PropertyType))
        .ToList();
    var resultType = DynamicClassFactory.CreateType(properties, false);
    var bindings = properties.Select(p => Expression.Bind(resultType.GetProperty(p.Name), Expression.Property(source, p.Name)));
    var result = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(resultType), bindings);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, dynamic>>(result, source);
}
```

Comment: does DynamicClassFactory Create an AnonymousType?

Comment: @johnny5 No. Anonymous types are C# compile-time feature. It's creating runtime types (with necessary caching). It's explained in the link - *Data classes are created in an in-memory assembly in the current application domain.*. The names of the runtime classes it generates are similar to C# generated anonymous types though :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea on how to go about this without using `Expressions`. Apparently, since `Reflection` in c# is slow as explained further in this [Article](http://mattwarren.org/2016/12/14/Why-is-Reflection-slow/), I decided to use a library called [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) to go about getting object properties.

==============

**Install FastMember**

Run the following command in PackageManagerConsole to install the library.

```
Install-Package FastMember -Version 1.4.1
```

**Write Function**

Our function/method is going to be an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for any generic type e.g `TEntity` that must be a `class` and takes an array of *fields* as parameter to tell the function which properties of `TEntity` to return.

```
using FastMember;
using Dynamic;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic

public static class Utilities
{
    public static dynamic GetDynamicFields<TEntity>(this TEntity entity, params string[] fields)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        dynamic dynamic = new ExpandoObject();
        // ExpandoObject supports IDictionary so we can extend it like this
        IDictionary<string,object> dictionary = dynamic as IDictionary<string,object>;

        TypeAccessor typeAccessor = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(TEntity));
        ObjectAccessor accessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(entity);
        IDictionary<string,Member> members = typeAccessor.GetMembers().ToDictionary(x => x.Name);

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
        {
            if (members.ContainsKey(fields[i]))
            {
                var prop = members[fields[i]];

                if (dictionary.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
                    dictionary[prop.Name] = accessor[prop.Name];
                else
                    dictionary.Add(prop.Name, accessor[prop.Name]);
            }
        }

        return dynamic;
    }
}
```

**How To Use**

Using the method is simple and can be done like so:

```
Message msg = new Message();
dynamic result = msg.GetDynamicFields("Id","Text");
```

---

> In c#, `dynamic` is an example of an `ExpandoObject`. After looking at the code for `ExpandoObject` i realized that it implements `IDictionary<string,object>`. Therefore, this means that we can be able to extend it and add dynamic properties to it at runtime thus making it easier for us.

**TestCase Time**

Running a test-case on the above method using [NUnit](https://nunit.org/), takes approximately *40ms* which sounds good enough.

Hope this solution works for you or maybe gives you ideas on how to go about your problem.

Cheers!